# Order of operators initialization in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job with the classic shape of `datasource-operator1-operatorN-sink`.

From what I can observe, the `open()` method of `operator1` is invoked before the `open()` method of the `datasource`.

In the `open()` method of `operator1` I need to handle some business logic, that it is dependent of stuff which gets resolved at `datasource.open()`

1- Is there any way that I can restrain that the `operator1.open()` is not invoked until `datasource.open()` is?
2- Is there any way to communicate/signal from the `datasource.open()` method, to the `operator1.open()` method?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. But what underlying problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps we can suggest another approach.

Comment: the DS is stateful and working well restoring state (the last record read) ...downstream, we have an async function fitting records to an external service.  
By business reqs, the async function needs to resume also from the same record. I tried checkpointing the async function too ...but from what I observe, the last record checkpointed by the async function, may be not exactly the same as the one snapshoted by the datasource.
I'm looking for a mechanism so that the async function does not start until the datasource has restored its state, and communicated it to the async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to establish some sort of out-of-band communication between operators often gets folks into trouble. At best it can screw up performance, and at worst it can lead to deadlocks.

What you might try instead is to rely on the signaling pathway that already exists between the data source and the async function -- in other words, emit a specially encoded event from the data source that tells the async function it can start now, and have the async function wait for that special record before doing other processing.

Comment: Eventually, that’s sort of what I did. I quitted checkpointing the async operator. After failure, the first event emitted by the datasource brings a special flag, and I handle it in the run() method of the async function just once, instead of the open(). Thanks once more David